# Display classic view in Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu-11.10

I have installed Ubuntu 11.10 OS.By default it displays its stylish display.I want to configure it to display classic view which will display the task bar and the menu, to display all programs.
can anybody can tell, the steps to configure, for displaying classic view in Ubuntu 11.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback
```

Once this is done, reboot and before login in, at the bottom, select Classic view and it should work.

If for some reason the result isn't as good as your old Classic view, I recommend switching back to 11.04 (that's what i'm running on) since Classic view is already a part of that version.